# How to force my laptop to use the discrete GPU?

Tags: windows-7, gpu, sandy-bridge, optimus

My laptop (Asus X7BSV) is stuck using only the integrated GPU. It has a nVidia GT540M as well, but I cannot get it to work.

I am using a Windows 7 x64 with latest drivers.

This occurred after I attached an external USB monitor I need for work, and since then I cannot swap back to the nVidia GPU (`dxdiag` for example says that the primary GPU is the Intel integrated one).

Asus support asked me to completely reinstall the system, but that is something I do not want to do.
I checked the BIOS, there is no option as to what GPU to use. The nVidia card itself is working, since I can use CUDA on it, and it worked with a Ubuntu Live CD. In the nVidia software management I tried setting it to global setting, high performance GPU (nVidia), but that had no impact.

What am I missing here? I did uninstall/delete all drivers and software related to the external monitor, but that did not help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With my Latitude E6520 with Intel HD Graphics 3000, NVIDIA NVS 4200M, and Windows 7 Enterprise, I can use the NVIDIA Control Panel to force a specific processor per-application or globally.  Try either:

- Right clicking on the Desktop and selecting NVIDIA Control Panel
- Navigating to the Control Panel and searching for NVIDIA Control Panel

If you don't have it installed, make sure you have the latest NVIDIA drivers.

[image]

Under the NVIDIA Control Panel, navigate to **3D Settings -> Manage 3D Settings**.  Select the **Global Settings** tab and use the **Preferred graphics processor** drop-down to select **High-performance NVIDIA processor**.  Then hit the **Apply** button.  You may need to restart your computer.

Comment: That setting no longer exists.